# Doxygen : namespaces and CLANG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, doxygen

I try to document some C++ code, but the Doxygen parser is not able to understand my code because I use a special macro to define the namespaces.

For now, I bypass this detail.

So, I try to use clang, but I got tons of errors, mainly because it try to analyse the MS code. I got such kind of error messages with clang :

```
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\xtr1common:212:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\xtr1common:218:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\xstddef:399:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\xstddef:405:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\xstddef:635:2: error: 'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:592:45: error: '_To' does not refer to a value [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:592:50: error: '_From' does not refer to a value [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:593:2: error: expected class name [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:1284:32: error: unknown type name '__make_integer_seq' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:1284:50: error: expected ';' after alias declaration [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:1290:30: error: unknown type name 'make_integer_sequence' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:1290:51: error: expected ';' after alias declaration [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:1293:29: error: unknown type name 'make_index_sequence' [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\type_traits:1293:48: error: expected ';' after alias declaration [clang]
error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\limits:612:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t' [clang]
```

Comment: You can temm doxygen what values to use for macros (https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/preprocessing.html) when processing the code, or use a #define for the doxygen run that simplifies things. You can often use dummy defines for the doxygen run.

Comment: Try `clang-cl.exe` or `-fms-extensions` flag.

Comment: so... what is the question you are asking: how to make doxygen understand your code or how to solve the clang errors? You can have only 1 question per question